# How to hide python program from windows task manager

Tags: python, windows, taskmanager

I have this website blocker I use for my little brothers. The program needs to always run, and I've disabled functions for closing it. The problem is that they could still close the program by opening the task manager. Are there any ways to hide it from the task manager but still runs in the background

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot solve the problem by parental control (which some browsers support), you can either

- Create a service. It will still be in task manager, but not under processes
- Create two processes that would constantly check if the other one is present and rerun it when it disappears

I don't think it is possible to have a program not displayed by task manager.